# C#: How to write to a class from within itself?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, this

I'm attempting to make a class that can serialize and de-serialize itself to/from a XML file through the use of the .NET XmlSerializer class. I've got the save function ("SaveSettings") to work but the loading function isn't as straight forward.

Currently I'm having to pass a reference of the class variable to the function to get the load function to work("LoadSettings2") What would be ideal would be just using the 'this' keyword ("LoadSettings") Is there anyway to create a LoadSettings function that only needs to be passed a file path?

Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ApplicationSettings appSet = new ApplicationSettings();
        appSet.SourceDirectory = "here";
        appSet.DestinationDirectory = "there";

        appSet.SaveSettings(@"C:\Users\Connor\Desktop\Folder A\a.xml");
        //appSet.LoadSettings(@"C:\Users\Connor\Desktop\Folder A\a.xml"); //Doesn't work
        appSet.LoadSettings2(ref appSet, @"C:\Users\Connor\Desktop\Folder A\a.xml");
    }
}
```

ApplicationSettings.cs:

```
public class ApplicationSettings
{
    //Serialized
    public string SourceDirectory;
    public string DestinationDirectory;

    //Not Serialized
    public void SaveSettings(string filePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer XSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));
        StreamWriter strWrite = new StreamWriter(filePath);

        XSerializer.Serialize(strWrite, this);
        strWrite.Close();
    }

    public void LoadSettings(string filePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer XSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));
        StreamReader strRead = new StreamReader(filePath);

        //Ideal but will not work
        //this = (ApplicationSettings)XSerializer.Deserialize(strRead);
        strRead.Close();
    }

    public void LoadSettings2(ref ApplicationSettings appSettings, string filePath)
    {
        XmlSerializer XSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));
        StreamReader strRead = new StreamReader(filePath);

        appSettings = (ApplicationSettings)XSerializer.Deserialize(strRead);
        strRead.Close();
    }
}
```

-

--Answer---

Got it working by doing a member by member copy suggested by 'David M' But did it by using System.Reflection which means that no variable names were used. I believe only public variables are copied, more testing needed for the classes. Takes about 1.8s to preform 10k iterations.

```
public void LoadSettings(string filePath)
{
    XmlSerializer XSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));
    StreamReader strRead = new StreamReader(filePath);
    ApplicationSettings settingsRead = (ApplicationSettings)XSerializer.Deserialize(strRead);

    foreach (var field in typeof(ApplicationSettings).GetFields())
    {
        field.SetValue(this, field.GetValue(settingsRead));
    }

    strRead.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you had used properties instead of fields, they would be serialized.

Answer (score 2):

Make it a static factory method instead:

```
public static ApplicationSettings LoadSettings(string filePath)
{
    XmlSerializer XSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));
    using (StreamReader strRead = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        var result = (ApplicationSettings)XSerializer.Deserialize(strRead);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to deserialise to another instance, and member by member copy the values to the current one. Note you'll be better off with a `using` block for your `StreamReader` - the `Dispose` call will make sure the file handle is released.

Comment: I was looking at it for the programmers viewpoint of having identical ways of calling the load and save functions would be ideal. I was considering making it OO so that it could be a base class that it could be inherited by other settings classes (I don't know if that is possible it's just sort of a fun project idea to better understand OO stuff.) But as for answering my original question yes you are correct, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make `LoadSettings()` a `static` method and call it like so:

```
ApplicationSettings applicationSettings = ApplicationSettings.LoadSettings();
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by doing a member by member copy suggested by 'David M' But did it by using System.Reflection which means that no variable names were used. I believe only public variables are copied, more testing needed for the classes. Takes about 1.8s to preform 10k iterations.

```
public void LoadSettings(string filePath)
{
    XmlSerializer XSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationSettings));
    StreamReader strRead = new StreamReader(filePath);
    ApplicationSettings settingsRead = (ApplicationSettings)XSerializer.Deserialize(strRead);

    foreach (var field in typeof(ApplicationSettings).GetFields())
    {
        field.SetValue(this, field.GetValue(settingsRead));
    }

    strRead.Close();
}
```